# optimize.curve_fit with DataFrames

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, curve-fitting, scipy-optimize

I am working with several DataFrames (I will use just 2 of them as an example here).
I want to perform a fitting from the data of both of them, using `scipy.optimize.curve_fit`.

Mainly, I want that the columns from the dataframe named '*new_freqs*' to be my x-variable or independent variable and the columns from the dataframe named '*Tans*' to be my y-values or dependent variable. Both dataframes have a shape of (12,6), where the first column of '*new_freqs*' (x-values) are corresponded with the first column of '*Tans*' (y-values) and so on.

I include below the most relevant part of the code.

```
In[1]:
print(type(Tans), Tans.shape)
print(type(new_freqs), new_freqs.shape)
Out[1]:
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'> (12, 6)
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'> (12, 6)
```

I am traying to fit it to a straight line

```
def linear(frequencies,tau):
    return 2*np.pi*new_freqs*tau

popt, pcov = scipy.optimize.curve_fit(linear, new_freqs, Tans, p0=None, maxfev=1000)
tau = popt
fit = lambda frequencies: 2*np.pi*new_freqs*tau
fitted = linear(new_freqs,tau)
print(popt, pcov)
```

I would like to obtain the straight line from the fitting to plot it together with the data, and the values of 'tau' in an array of every set of (x,y).

I obtain this error:

```
ValueError: object too deep for desired array

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\\XXXXXXXXX.py", line 210, in <module>
    popt, pcov = scipy.optimize.curve_fit(linear, new_freqs, Tans, p0=None, maxfev=1000)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\minpack.py", line 763, in curve_fit
    res = leastsq(func, p0, Dfun=jac, full_output=1, **kwargs)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\minpack.py", line 401, in leastsq
    gtol, maxfev, epsfcn, factor, diag)
minpack.error: Result from function call is not a proper array of floats.
```

I would really appreciate your hints and help.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue with the following code (if it can be useful for someone):

```
cols_name = list(Tan.columns.values)
def linear(new_freqs, tau):
    return 2.0*np.pi*new_freqs*tau

def fit_linear(new_freqs, Tan):
    Taus_lin = []
    Fit_tang_lin = []
    count = 0
    for count in range(len(cols_names)):
        popt, pcov = scipy.optimize.curve_fit(linear, new_freqs.iloc[:,count], Tan.iloc[:,count], p0=None, maxfev=5000)
        tau = popt
        fitted_Tan = linear(new_freqs.iloc[:,count],tau)
        Taus_lin.append(tau)
        Fit_tang_lin.append(fitted_Tan)
    Taus_lin = pd.DataFrame(np.transpose(Taus_lin), columns=cols_names)
    Fit_tang_lin = pd.DataFrame(np.transpose(Fit_tang_lin), columns=cols_names)
    return Taus_lin, Fit_tang_lin
```